# Send shortcut to specific folder from the 'Send To' context menu?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, send-to

I want to add an option to the "Send to" menu to allow a shortcut to a file to be created and sent to a folder I specify. I have been trying to do this using the solution posted to the questions asked here back in 2013 ([First](https://superuser.com/questions/591752/create-shortcut-to-a-specific-folder-in-the-send-to-context-menu) and [Second](https://superuser.com/questions/606245/how-to-create-send-to-folder-similar-to-send-to-desktop-shortcut/606246#606246)) but without success.

The links to shortcut.zip were not working but I managed to find what I think is the correct program - [Shortcuts Map](http://www.download25.com/install/shortcuts-map.html). Although I could extract to the System32 folder as suggested, the setup file will not run from there. If I install normally, it runs fine but it only finds shortcuts related to my desktop or Start Menu and I'm assuming this is not enough for what I need. Have I missed something obvious or will this simply not work on Windows 10? Or have I not found the correct shortcut program?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Select and copy the destination folder in Windows Explorer.

Type `shell:sendto` in Run dialog (**Winkey+R**).

Right click and blank spot and choose *Paste Shortcut*.

Sending in *Send To* is equivalent to dragging.

```
Ctrl + Drag is copy the file (the default drag action between drives)

Shift + Drag is move the file (the default drag action on the same drive)

Ctrl + Shift + Drag is create a shortcut to the object
```

While it doesn't apply to *Send To*

```
Right Mouse Drag will popup a menu when you drop it asking what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. I can edit the sendto menu by hitting Windows Key+R and type: shell:sendto, hit enter, and can then add remove program or location shortcuts to it via right-clicking in an empty area of the sendTo folder, choosing new>shortcut. That does only copy the file, so I would have to delete the original if I want it moved.

Instead of sendto, I used the registry hack that adds 'move to' to the right menu options so I can just 'move' what I want to a folder, but I have to select the folder. To avoid that,  I can make a new reg file to merge, editing it something like I did in the attached.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsVV5.png)

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to move the file though - it's like the Send To Desktop (create shortcut) I want to do - only to a folder I have chosen

Answer (score 0):

You need a script to accomplish this.

THe script (without error checking or creaton confirmation) would take the path of the item that was right-clicked, launch the `BrowseForFolder` dialog, and crate a shortcut to the selected item in the location seleted in the dialog.

It uses two COM objects: `wscript.shell` to create the shortcut and `shell.application`to display the `BrowseForFolder` dialog.

```
$FormatArgs      = @(
    (New-Object -Com shell.application).BrowseForFolder(0,'Select Shortcut Location',0).Self.Path
    (Get-Item $args[0]).Name
)
$Link            = (New-Object -com wscript.shell).CreateShortcut(( '{0}\{1}.lnk' -f $FormatArgs ))
$Link.TargetPath = $Args[0]
$Link.Save()
```

Save as `SendShortcutToFolder.ps1` in a location that can be accessed by anyone expected to use it.

Then, in your `SendTo` folder, launch the `New Shortcut` wizard and for the target, enter:
`PowerShell -File "<path to SendShortcutToFolder.ps1>"`

and save it with whatever text you want to appear in the menu -- I like `Folder… (Create Shortcut)`  ('…' is the ellipsis character: `U+2026` / `<alt>+0133`)

---

***Important***: If you've never enabled local scripts to run in **PowerShell**, you need to do that *once* before the shortcut will work. This is done by opening a  **PowerShell** console window and executing:
`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
Then close the console window.

---

You will see a blank **PowerShell** window behind the dailog box until the dialog is closed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. I think I may have made things a little more complicated than I needed to, though. I really meant I wanted to set the folder to one I wanted, rather than needing to select each time. I will try playing with the script but if you have any pointers, that would be great